# C# and Interfaces - Explicit vs. Implicit

Tags: c#, .net, interface, casting, duck-typing

In C#, if a class *has all the correct methods/signatures for an Interface*, but **doesn't** explicitly implement it like:

```
class foo : IDoo {}
```

Can the class still be cast as that interface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not like Objective-C and some other languages. You should explicitly declare interface implementation.

Comment: So it will throw an exception if I cast it as the interface?

Comment: Yes, if your class doesn't explicity implement the interface you will get an exception if you try to cast it as such.

Comment: You can only cast an object to an object that appears somewhere in its inheritance chain (this includes interfaces implemented in the inheritance chain).

Comment: Lest there be any confusion, keep in mind that "explicitly implementing an interface" has another meaning in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Explicitly *declare* interface implementation is not supposed to mean "explicit interface implementation*

Comment: @Mehrdad - Indeed, my comment was directed at @Justin's response. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: It won't really throw an exception because you'll never make it that far. You can't even compile if you have a class which does not implement all the members of the interface.

Comment: @Rex: The OP clearly specifies that the class has all the required stuff for an interface, but doesn't declare that it implements the interface. In this case, if you try to cast, it will compile but throw InvalidCastException at runtime.

Answer (score 17):

**Duck Typing**

What you are alluding to is referred to as "[duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_Typing)" (named after the idiom "if it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck").

With duck-typing an interface implementation is implicit once you have implemented the relevant members (just as you describe) however .NET does not currently have any broad support for this.

With the emergent dynamic language features planned for the future, I wouldn't be surprised if this were supported natively by the runtime in the near future.

In the mean time, you can synthesise duck-typing via reflection, with [a library such as this](http://www.deftflux.net/blog/page/Duck-Typing-Project.aspx), which would allow you to do a duck-typed cast like this: `IDoo myDoo = DuckTyping.Cast<IDoo>(myFoo)`

**Some Trivia**

Interestingly, there is one small place where duck-typing is in use in C# today — the `foreach` operator. Krzysztof Cwalina [states](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2007/07/18/DuckNotation.aspx) that in order to be enumerable by the `foreach` operator, a class must:

> Provide a public method GetEnumerator
>   that takes no parameters and returns a
>   type that has two members: a) a method
>   MoveMext that takes no parameters and
>   return a Boolean, and b) a property
>   Current with a getter that returns an
>   Object.

Notice that he makes no mention of `IEnumerable` nor `IEnumerator`. Although it is common to implement these interfaces when creating an enumerable class, if you were to drop the interfaces but leave the implementation, your class would still be enumerable by `foreach`. Voila! Duck-typing! ([Example code here](http://www.danielfortunov.com/software/%24daniel_fortunovs_adventures_in_software_development/2009/07/28/duck_typing).)

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't time to check duck typing thingy and always forgot about it. You served information on silver plate.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that IDoo has any members, this code won't compile. If IDoo has no members, then yes, the cast is safe (but obviously of limited use).

Comment: The OP clearly specifies *if a class has all the correct methods/signatures for an Interface*, but if it doesn't, then your point is notable.

Answer (score 3):

This would basically require Duck Typing to work in C#, which does not happen automatically.

There are some [libraries](http://www.deftflux.net/blog/post/Duck-Typing-version-0927-released.aspx) that can do this, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class A
{
   public void DoSomething();
}

public interface IDoSomething
{
   void DoSomething();
}

public class B : A, IDoSomething
{ }
```

B satisfies IDoSomething.DoSomething by inheriting from A